# Existence of a big connected component in a planar graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, percolation

Let $G$ be a connected finite subgraph of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. We know that we can define the dual graph $G^{\ast}$ of $G$ having vertices the faces of $G$ and edges between two vertices at distance $1$ that are lying in the same face. Let $0,x\in G$ and let $\gamma$ be (one of the) the shortest path joining $0$ to $x$, of length $n$. I am wondering if one can say something along the lines of : There exists a dual (that is, a connected component of $G^{\ast}$) connected component (equivalently, a face of $G$) of size greater or equal to $n/2$, or maybe $n/4$ ?

I think that the result is true but I have no idea how to utilize the fact that $\gamma$ is minimal in order to conclude. If $\gamma$ only uses edges going in the direct $x\cdot \vec{e_1}$ or $x\cdot \vec{e_2}$, then I can juste take the dual boundary of $G$, which is connected and has length $\geq 2n$. But if $\gamma$ is highly suboptimal (doing "U-turns" and things like that), then the dual boundary does not suffice and I am stuck. Also, do we have similar result in higher dimensions ?

Edit : Here $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is the square lattice. The definition of the dual graph I use here is the one commonly used in percolation. We define the dual graph of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to be the graph having vertex set $$V((\mathbb{Z}^2)^{\ast})= V(\mathbb{Z}^2+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}^2),$$ which means that each face of the square lattice is a vertex of the dual graph. We add an edge between two adjacent faces, which means that $(\mathbb{Z}^2)^{\ast}$ is a translated of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. We then define the dual of any subgraph $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to be the graph with dual edges (that is, edges in $(\mathbb{Z}^2)^{\ast}$) that correspond to edges of $\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus G$ having at least one endpoint in $G$.

The dual of a line consisting of $n$ edges is therefore a (dual) path that "contains" the line. In this case it would correspond to the "boundary" of the line in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Thanks to anyone who can help me :)

Comment: What graph is $Z_2$? Is it the square lattice? I have a hard  figuring your definition of dual graph, especially for edges . This is not the classical definition of duality in planar graphs isn't it? Otherwise, the planar dual is always connected. If you could provide an example, that could help to grasp the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: So if we take a horizontal line of length $n$, then we get $n $ disconnected components made of a single vertical edge? That won't give you a big connected component?

Comment: Sorry I have a hard time speaking English, I corrected my definition and now it is 100% correct. In your example, the dual will be a contour that contains the line, so that you will get a big connected component. The difficulty is when your path does a lot of "turns".

Comment: If your graph is a path visiting all the vertices of a square of size $N$ then $n =N^2$. Therefore, the dual is only the contour of the square, of size $\mathcal {O}(\sqrt{n}) $

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken but this case you will also get a big dual path : if your path goes vertically from $(0,0)$ to say $(0,10)$ and the $(1,10)$ all the way to $(1,0)$, then every edge connecting a vertex from the left line to the right line of your path will be closed, which means that you have a dual line of length 10.

Comment: As I wrote it in my edit, any edge in $E(\mathbb{Z}^2)\setminus E(G)$ having \textbf{at least} one endpoint in $G$, is in the dual of $G$.

Comment: You are correct, i overlooked it

Answer (score 1):

In the following graph, the biggest face scales with a size of $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ compared to length of the shortest path between $A$ and $B$

[image]